# What should be my query to get a list of nodes in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Data Structure]

What should be my query be if I want to get the list of all records which gender = 0 and userType = 1? I'm quite new to firebase and I can't find any sources that teaches compound some queries.

Comment: use addListenerForSingleValueEvent like http://stackoverflow.com/a/36611301/3496570

Comment: but you should better create array of user class with key 0 ,1,2 and so on. And read list of User

Comment: So what you are trying to imply is that I'll get the list of users then filter it one by one programmatically

Comment: firebase have function for it . Use startAt ,endAt and orderBy for querying data like http://stackoverflow.com/a/26701282/3496570 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/37952868/3496570

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> first of all create a node name `userList` and add `instances` of user with key 0,1,2,3 and so on like in [screen shot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30744224/3496570) in question. It becomes an `array of userList`

```
List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
Firebase ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

  ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
          for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            <User> user = postSnapshot.getValue(<User>.class);
            userList .add(user);
          }
      }
      @Override
      public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
          Log.e("The read failed: " ,firebaseError.getMessage());
      }
  });
```

And you can also use **Firebase RecyclerAdapter** [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35497309/3496570)

`Firebase` is **no SQL**. it doesn't have `where` clause. You can use `orderBy`,`startAt`,`endAt` function to achieve filtering . See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26701282/3496570) and [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37952868/3496570).

**Filter most on the server, do the rest on the client**

```
 orderBy('gender')
  .startAt('0').endAt('0')
```

and in onDataChange

```
  for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) 
  {
       <User> user = postSnapshot.getValue(<User>.class);
       if(user.getUserType == 1) 
           userList .add(user);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @nepster