# How to extract a list of objects from Firebase DataSnapshot on android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to convert all Firebase `DataSnapshot` children to a list in android.

Something like this:

```
mFirebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

mFirebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> td = (ArrayList<String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        //notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27848313/firebase-retrieve-child-android

Comment: Answer below. But it's partially a guess, because "its not working" is incredibly vague and you don't include a snippet of your data. If my answer doesn't address your problem: what error do you get? What does you data look like (a copy/paste sample of it, no screenshots and no descriptions)?

Comment: Try This : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886546/how-to-get-all-child-list-from-firebase-android/36600791#36600791

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/@alex.mamo/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-realtime-database-to-a-list-of-objects-53f27b33c8f3) will definitely help.

Answer (score 101):

I hope below code works

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

  ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
          Log.e("Count " ,""+snapshot.getChildrenCount());
          for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            <YourClass> post = postSnapshot.getValue(<YourClass>.class);
            Log.e("Get Data", post.<YourMethod>());
          }
      }
      @Override
      public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
          Log.e("The read failed: " ,firebaseError.getMessage());
      }
  });
```

Comment: When i print the log it is null. Could you help me?

Comment: Don't forget to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` instead of `addValueEventListener()` if you only need that data once.

Answer (score 38):

Firebase stores a sequence of values in this format:

```
"-K-Y_Rhyxy9kfzIWw7Jq": "Value 1"
"-K-Y_RqDV_zbNLPJYnOA": "Value 2"
"-K-Y_SBoKvx6gAabUPDK": "Value 3"
```

If that is how you have them, you are getting the wrong type. The above structure is represented as a `Map`, not as a `List`:

```
mFirebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

mFirebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Map<String, Object> td = (HashMap<String,Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

        List<Object> values = td.values();

        //notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: I want parent list of  "-K-Y_Rhyxy9kfzIWw7Jq": "Value 1"
"-K-Y_RqDV_zbNLPJYnOA": "Value 2"
"-K-Y_SBoKvx6gAabUPDK": "Value 3"

Comment: Is it ok to do `Map<String, MyDataObject> = (HashMap<String, MyDataObject>) dataSnapshot.getValue();` or do I have to convert Object into MyDataObject?

Comment: @Frank, Android studio is showing red underline on this line List<Object> values =td.values();...ERROR:- can't cast the collection object to list object..throwing error in stacktrace..

Comment: @Frank Thankyou, ``List<Object> values = td.values();`` is very nice to know.

Comment: @NarendraBaratam I had same problem. use this way instead: `List<Object> values = new Arraylist<>(td.values());`

Answer (score 27):

```
FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
 DatabaseReference databaseReference =    mFirebaseDatabase.getReference(FIREBASE_URL);
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.v(TAG,""+ childDataSnapshot.getKey()); //displays the key for the node
                    Log.v(TAG,""+ childDataSnapshot.child(--ENTER THE KEY NAME eg. firstname or email etc.--).getValue());   //gives the value for given keyname
                }
            }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 13):

as Frank said **Firebase** stores sequence of values in the format of `"key": "Value"`
which is a **Map** structure

to get **List** from this sequence you have to

1. initialize **GenericTypeIndicator** with **HashMap** of **String** and your **Object**.
2. get value of **DataSnapShot** as **GenericTypeIndicator** into **Map**.
3. initialize **ArrayList** with **HashMap** values.

---

```
GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>> objectsGTypeInd = new GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>>() {};
Map<String, Object> objectHashMap = dataSnapShot.getValue(objectsGTypeInd);
ArrayList<Object> objectArrayList = new ArrayList<Object>(objectHashMap.values());
```

---

Works fine for me, Hope it helps.

Comment: Found this buried in the doco https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/GenericTypeIndicator.html

Answer (score 11):

I did something like this :

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    Map<String, Object> objectMap = (HashMap<String, Object>)    
             dataSnapshot.getValue();
    List<Match> = new ArrayList<Match>();
    for (Object obj : objectMap.values()) {
        if (obj instanceof Map) {
            Map<String, Object> mapObj = (Map<String, Object>) obj;
            Match match = new Match();
            match.setSport((String) mapObj.get(Constants.SPORT));
            match.setPlayingWith((String) mapObj.get(Constants.PLAYER));
            list.add(match);
        }
    }
  }
  @Override
  public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

  }
});
```

Comment: Am I understanding right? You are looping every time even you add only one Match type value?

Answer (score 7):

In my case only given solution worked fine.

Screenshot of **Firebase ArrayList structure**:

[image]

How to **fetch whole list** from **Firebase** from **DataSnapshot**.

```
GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, List<Education>>> genericTypeIndicator = new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, List<Education>>>() {};
Map<String, List<Education>> hashMap = dataSnapshot.getValue(genericTypeIndicator);

for (Map.Entry<String,List<Education>> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
      List<Education> educations = entry.getValue();
        for (Education education: educations){
             Log.i(TAG, education.Degree);
         }
}
```

**Education.java:** (Model class).

```
public class Education implements Serializable{

    public String Degree;
    public String Result;
}
```

Hope this would works fine.

Answer (score 6):

```
    @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               User user = postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
               list.add(user);
           }
           for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
           {
               Log.e("Name",list.get(i).getname());
               Log.e("Phone",list.get(i).getphone());

           }
       }
       @Override
       public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
       Log.e("error",firebaseError.getMessage());
       }
   });
```

**Class model**

```
class User{

String name;

String phone;

public String getname() {
    return name;
}

public void setname(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public String getphone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setphone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
}
```

**List binding**

```
List<User> list= new ArrayList <>();
```

**this work for you**

Answer (score 6):

If you use Kotlin, the next one is a good solution:

```
myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
  override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
      val list = dataSnapshot.children.map { it.getValue(YourClass::class.java)!! }
      Log.d("TAG", "Value is: $list")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Saving and Retriving data to - from Firebase **( deprecated ver 2.4.2 )**

```
Firebase fb_parent = new Firebase("YOUR-FIREBASE-URL/");
Firebase fb_to_read = fb_parent.child("students/names");
Firebase fb_put_child = fb_to_read.push(); // REMEMBER THIS FOR PUSH METHOD

//INSERT DATA TO STUDENT - NAMES  I Use Push Method
fb_put_child.setValue("Zacharia"); //OR fb_put_child.setValue(YOUR MODEL) 
fb_put_child.setValue("Joseph"); //OR fb_put_child.setValue(YOUR MODEL) 
fb_put_child.setValue("bla blaaa"); //OR fb_put_child.setValue(YOUR MODEL) 

//GET DATA FROM FIREBASE INTO ARRAYLIST
fb_to_read.addValuesEventListener....{
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot result){
        List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>(); // Result will be holded Here
        for(DataSnapshot dsp : result.getChildren()){
            lst.add(String.valueOf(dsp.getKey())); //add result into array list
        }
        //NOW YOU HAVE ARRAYLIST WHICH HOLD RESULTS




for(String data:lst){ 
         Toast.make(context,data,Toast.LONG_LENGTH).show; 
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mDatabase.child("token").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              for (DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
              {
                 String key= snapshot.getKey();
                 String value=snapshot.getValue().toString();
              }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(ListUser.this,databaseError.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Only work If child have no `SubChild`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Works Like a Charm

```
final DatabaseReference senderDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constant.NODE_MESSAGE).child(myId + "_" + otherId);

    senderDb.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Map<String, Object> td = (HashMap<String,Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

            for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                DatabaseReference objRef = senderDb.child( childDataSnapshot.getKey());
                Map<String,Object> taskMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                taskMap.put("is_read", "1");
                objRef.updateChildren(taskMap); //should I use setValue()...?
                Log.v("Testing",""+ childDataSnapshot.getKey()); //displays the key for the node
            }

            //notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to write a custom Deserializer and then loop it and get the values of the hasmap.

Custom Deserializer:-

```
public class UserDetailsDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<AllUserDetailsKeyModel> {
  /*
    bebebejunskjd:{
      "email": "akhilbv1@gmail.com",
          "mobileNum": "12345678",
          "password": "1234567",
          "username": "akhil"}*/
  @Override public AllUserDetailsKeyModel deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
      JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

    final JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Type AllUserDetailsResponseModel =
        new TypeToken<HashMap<String, AllUserDetailsResponseModel>>(){}.getType();

    HashMap<String, AllUserDetailsResponseModel> user =
        gson.fromJson(jsonObject, AllUserDetailsResponseModel);
    AllUserDetailsKeyModel result = new AllUserDetailsKeyModel();
    result.setResult(user);
    return result;
  }


}
```

The code in comments is my object model and u should replaceAllUserDetailsKeyModel with your model class and add this to the rest client like below:-

```
private Converter.Factory createGsonConverter() {
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(AllUserDetailsKeyModel.class, new UserDetailsDeserializer());
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    return GsonConverterFactory.create(gson);
  }
```

This the custom Convertor for Retrofit.

In your onResponse you just loop with hasmaps and get value by key and my model class looks like below:-

```
public class AllUserDetailsKeyModel {

  private Map<String, AllUserDetailsResponseModel> result;

  public Map<String, AllUserDetailsResponseModel> getResult() {
    return result;
  }

  public void setResult(Map<String, AllUserDetailsResponseModel> result) {
    this.result = result;
  }

}
```

probably you need to give a Type T where T is your data Type and my model consists only of a hashmap and getters and setters for that.

And finally set Custom Convertor to retrofit like below:- `.addConverterFactory(createGsonConverter())`

Let me know if you need more clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

### Use GenericTypeIndicator to get List of Child Node from Firebase ArrayList structured DataBase

```
   //Start of Code
   Firebase ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
   ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot){
         GenericTypeIndicator<List<YourClassName>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<YourClassName>>{};
         List<YourClassName> messages = snapshot.getValue(t);
         Log.d("Get Data Size", messages.size());
          }
      }
      @Override
      public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError){
          Log.e("The read failed: ",firebaseError.getMessage());
      }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is why your code doesn't work.

this your code:

> ```
> Firebase ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
>
>   ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
>       @Override
>       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
>           Log.e("Count " ,""+snapshot.getChildrenCount());
>           for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
>             <YourClass> post = postSnapshot.getValue(<YourClass>.class);
>             Log.e("Get Data", post.<YourMethod>());
>           }
>       }
>       @Override
>       public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
>           Log.e("The read failed: " ,firebaseError.getMessage());
>       }
>   })
> ```

you miss the simplest thing: `getChildren()`

```
FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getReference("Donald Trump");

reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            int count = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount(); // retrieve number of childrens under Donald Trump

            String[] hairColors = new String[count];

            index = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                hairColors[index] = datas.getValue(String.class);

            }
            index ++

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            Toast(MainActivity.this, "hairColors : " + hairColors[i], toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

    }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });
```

Comment: index ++; must be inside the  for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>();
mKeyRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String temp = childDataSnapshot.getKey();
                keyList.add(temp);
                i = keyList.size();

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
```

This code is working fine to add all firebase key into arraylist, you can do it with firebase values, of other static values.

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please [edit] your answer and add some words explaining how it solves the problem and/or how it is different from the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference mMainMenuRef = mRootRef.child("tut_master");//main
        DatabaseReference mSubMenuRef = mMainMenuRef.child("english");//sub
        List<Tutorial>   tutorialNames=new ArrayList<>();
        mSubMenuRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    long id = ds.child("id").getValue(Long.class);
                    String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);

                    Tutorial tut = new Tutorial();
                    tut.setTutId(id+"");
                    tut.setTutName(name);
                    tutList.add(tut);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase=  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference=  firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    private DatabaseReference mChildReference= databaseReference.child("data");

  mChildReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User commandObject = ds.getValue(User.class);
                    Log.d("TAG", commandObject.getMsg());
                }
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,dataSnapshot.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

This will help you, you just have to create a model class containing String msg.

Answer (score 0):

Use Gson is my favorite solution.

```
mFirebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Type StringListType = new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType();
        List<String> td = new Gson().fromJson(dataSnapshot.getValue(), StringListType);
    }
});
```

if you think the code to get TypeToken is unintuitive. You can write a class to contain all types you need. So next time, you can get those types quickly.

```
class TypeTokens{
    static public final Type StringListType = new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType();
    static public final Type StringMapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
    static public final Type LongMapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Long>>(){}.getType();
    static public final Type DateMapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Date>>(){}.getType();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here goes my 2 cents contribution (in Kotlin):

```
    private fun getData(childUid:String) {
    
    refDB = firebaseDB.reference.child(MAIN_DATABASE_FOLDER).child(childUid)
    if(childEventDataListener == null) {
        childEventDataListener = object : ChildEventListener {
            override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                
                for(snap in snapshot.children) {
                    val newParcel = snapshot.getValue(YourClassConverter::class.java)!!
                }
            }
            
            override fun onChildChanged(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) { }
            override fun onChildRemoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot) { }
            override fun onChildMoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {}
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}
        }
        refDB.addChildEventListener(childEventDataListener!!)
    }
}
```

The class YourClassConverter shall follow this rule as noted in the getValue header's comment shown below. I prefer to use this converter since I can control the default values passed when some of them are not defined in the firebase.

This method is used to marshall the data contained in this snapshot into a class of your choosing. The class must fit 2 simple constraints:
The class must have a default constructor that takes no arguments
The class must define public getters for the properties to be assigned. Properties without a public getter will be set to their default value when an instance is deserialized
An example class might look like:

```
 class Message {
     private String author;
     private String text;

     private Message() {}

     public Message(String author, String text) {
         this.author = author;
         this.text = text;
     }

     public String getAuthor() {
         return author;
     }

     public String getText() {
         return text;
     }
 }


 // Later
 Message m = snapshot.getValue(Message.class);
```