# View FireBase data

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

How do I display the data that signed up in Firebase in my application and make them persist in it, so they can be viewed even offline Would you like some practical examples ...

//Classe dos usuarios

```
public class Usuarios {

private String Nome;
private String Data;
private String Rg;
private String Cpf;
private String Endereco;
private String Doenca;
private String Profissao;

public Usuarios(String Nome, String Data, String Rg, String Cpf, String Endereco, String Doenca, String Profissao) {
    this.Nome = Nome;
    this.Data = Data;
    this.Rg = Rg;
    this.Cpf = Cpf;
    this.Endereco = Endereco;
    this.Doenca = Doenca;
    this.Profissao = Profissao;
}
public Usuarios() {

}

public String getNome() {
    return Nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    Nome = nome;
}

public String getData() {
    return Data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    Data = data;
}

public String getRg() {
    return Rg;
}

public void setRg(String rg) {
    Rg = rg;
}

public String getCpf() {
    return Cpf;
}

public void setCpf(String cpf) {
    Cpf = cpf;
}

public String getEndereco() {
    return Endereco;
}

public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
    Endereco = endereco;
}

public String getDoenca() {
    return Doenca;
}

public void setDoenca(String doenca) {
    Doenca = doenca;
}

public String getProfissao() {
    return Profissao;
}

public void setProfissao(String profissao) {
    Profissao = profissao;
   }
}
```

//Class Main
    public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
private void writeNewUser(String userId,String Nome, String Data, String Rg, String Cpf, String Endereco, String Doenca, String Profissao) {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
    Usuarios user = new Usuarios(Nome, Data, Rg, Cpf, Endereco, Doenca, Profissao);

    myRef.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Usuarios user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Usuarios.class);

           String nome = Usuarios.class.getName();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

//Classe cadastro 
    `public void cadastro(View view){
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
        myRef.child("Users").child(etRg.getText().toString()).child("UserName").setValue(etNome.getText().toString());
        myRef.child("Users").child(etRg.getText().toString()).child("UserData").setValue(etData.getText().toString());
        myRef.child("Users").child(etRg.getText().toString()).child("UserRg").setValue(etRg.getText().toString());
        myRef.child("Users").child(etRg.getText().toString()).child("UserCpf").setValue(etCpf.getText().toString());
        myRef.child("Users").child(etRg.getText().toString()).child("UserEndereco").setValue(etEndereco.getText().toString());
        myRef.child("Users").child(etRg.getText().toString()).child("UserDoenca").setValue(etDoenca.getText().toString());
        myRef.child("Users").child(etRg.getText().toString()).child("UserProfissao").setValue(etProfissao.getText().toString());
    }
    public void mostrarDados(View view){
        textViewInfo.setText("UserName");
    }`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJa3f.png)

Comment: You want To Read a data From Firebase?

Comment: yes I want to catch the hum of specific User and colocalos Data hum textview

Comment: String nome = Usuarios.class.getName(); change this to  String nome = nome.getName();

Comment: and show me your database photo

Comment: has a photo at the end of the Code

Answer (score 0):

1st of All it is not best practice to save your data, witch way you doing this, make a Java POJO object to save data Into firebase, [here is video Tutorial i make to save java Obj to Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GDpv1XvqBA)  , here is Example How you Writer java obj to firebase

step one make your java Class

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class User {

    public String username;
    public String email;

    public User() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public User(String username, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

step 2

```
private void writeNewUser(String userId, String name, String email) {
    User user = new User(name, email);

    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
}
```

Then You need add ValueEventListener To read data

```
      myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                         User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

String Name user.getName();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

For more read [The google Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data)

Comment: Man I did as changes in class que fast you sugerio however now she is not no more saving the data ...

Comment: do you get your data?

Comment: no they did not come to the bank, the application and displays an error

Comment: this is error NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.matheus.kypy.Main.cadastro(Main.java:76)

Comment: delete this line and try this myRef.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);http://stackoverflow.com/a/32901133/5727285

Comment: I Can not entender What the boy makes no link code ... I never imagined it would be so hard to save data and display them using a api :(

Comment: its not hard share your code on git hub i will check what doing wrong

Comment: this how i done ,https://github.com/ameerhamza6733/FirebaseReadAndWriteDemo/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/ameerhamza/firebabseyoutubetest

Comment: ahhh I do not know What do u already I have a bursting head, I I used your code to guthub and IT tb NOT work here, HE monstra In records What IS RUNNING is everything BUT no console do firebase IT NOT displays nd, OR brings back as information ... I am NOT getting Doing nothing today

Comment: have you change your fire base rules?

Comment: i am gatting your data in my firebase, so make sure you study the logs(log.e("","')) in your android study , here is video link to video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SO1x2rENZMk

Comment: guy thank your video lessons helped me a lot ... I did everything according to their videos and it worked, the only problem is that in their video classes has nothing talking about how to display this data in textview or a listview ... you could help me with this, or will shed some video lesson on your channel about it ???

Comment: give me your team viewer accesss i can show you how to show data to textview

Comment: id:327 549 865 pw:5047

Comment: let me downlaod the TV

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/ameerhamza6733 come on fb , and TV not connecting