# Android Firebase array

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing an Android app using Firebase for cloud database. Its basically a multiple choice survey question app. Imported to Firebase I had

```
{
  "multiple_choice" : {
    "-K2222222222" : {
      "question" : "Question text",
      "opt1" : "answer 1",
      "opt2" : "answer 2",
      "opt3" : "answer 3"
    }
  }
}
```

I add a MultipleChoice class like so

```
public class MultipleChoice {

    private String id;
    private String question;
    private String opt1;
    private String opt2;
    private String opt3;

    public MultipleChoice() {
    }

    public MultipleChoice(String question, String opt1, String opt2, String opt3) {
        this.question = question;
        this.opt1 = opt1;
        this.opt2 = opt2;
        this.opt3 = opt3;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getOpt1() {
        return opt1;
    }

    public void setOpt1(String opt1) {
        this.opt1 = opt1;
    }

    public String getOpt2() {
        return opt2;
    }

    public void setOpt2(String opt2) {
        this.opt2 = opt2;
    }

    public String getOpt3() {
        return opt3;
    }

    public void setOpt3(String opt3) {
        this.opt3 = opt3;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

}
```

which allows me to retrieve this data in the main class using Firebase references.

Now I want to make it like an array of options although FB doesn't literally work that way, so it can take any number of options instead of a fixed 3 or whatever. This json file loaded into FB

```
{
      "multiple_choice" : {
        "-K2222222222" : {
          "question" : "Should Britian leave the EU?",
          "options" : {
            "1" : "answer 1",
            "2" : "answer 2",
            "3" : "answer 3"
          },
        }
      }
    }
```

but I can't figure out how to add methods in the MultipleChoice class. And ideas how to get the effect of an array so I can retrieve options[0] etc. or options/"1"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array starts from index 0, so your database structure should be

```
{
    "multiple_choice" : {
        "-K2222222222" : {
            "question" : "Should Britian leave the EU?",
            "options" : {
                "0" : "answer 1",
                "1" : "answer 2",
                "2" : "answer 3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the model class for each multiple_choice

```
public class MultipleChoice {
    private String id;
    private String question;
    private List<String> options;

    public List<String> getOptions() {
        return options;
    }

    public void setOptions(List<String> options) {
        this.options = options;
    }

    ... constructor and other getter setter...
}
```

This is an example of how to retrieve each option from the list

```
MultipleChoice multipleChoice = dataSnapshot.getValue(MultipleChoice.class);
String firstOption = multipleChoice.getOptions().get(0);
String secondOption = multipleChoice.getOptions().get(1);
String thirdOption = multipleChoice.getOptions().get(2);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Map:

```
 private Map<String, String> options;
```

[how to get all child list from Firebase android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886546/how-to-get-all-child-list-from-firebase-android)