# Get list of children of Firebase StorageReference

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I have StorageReference object which have few children. Is there any way to traverse these children in order to obtain their individual StorageReference. Is there anything similar to ValueEventListener which can be added to FirebaseReference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get all child list from Firebase android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886546/how-to-get-all-child-list-from-firebase-android)

Comment: @Francisco Durdin Garcia it's not duplicate. I am asking about StorageRefernce , we can not add ValueEventListener like we do for  FirebaseReference.