# How to update firebase database values

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried too many times but not works this code .How to update specific  fields in Firebase database which is mentioned in structure

Here is my structure:

```
Blog
-LOkCTZQtuMIPT_c9ESK
  desc: "wow"
  id: "-LOkCTZQtuMIPT_c9ESK"
  image:"firebase image"
  title:"gh"
  uid:"6757576gfgHh6"
```

So how i can update the desc,image,title these particular fields only with the help of id

Here is my code:

```
 mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");

    mDatabaseUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(mCurrentUser.getUid());

private void startPosting() {

    mProgress.setMessage("Posting...");

    final String title_val = mPostTitle.getText().toString().trim();
    final String desc_val = mNameFieldUpdate.getText().toString().trim();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val) && mImageUri != null) {

        mProgress.show();

        final StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Blog_Images").child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());
        filepath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
                final Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                final String id = mDatabase.getKey();

                mDatabaseUser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                        mDatabase.child(id).child("title").setValue(title_val);
                        mDatabase.child(id).child("desc").setValue(desc_val);
                        mDatabase.child(id).child("image").setValue(downloadUri.toString());
                        mProgress.dismiss();

                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Update_Post.this, Main2Activity.class);
                        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(mainIntent);
                        finish();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: is the photo being uploaded?

Comment: yep everything is uploading but it creating new post now overwriting the post

Comment: Is because you are getting the key from the blog, instaed of getting the key from the blog child

Comment: Hey cutiko can you tell how to get key from the blog child in this code

Comment: ok @PeterHaddad i am trying to implement this

Comment: Usually you can get it because it was previously seleceted like clicked from a list but if there is some practice code check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886546/how-to-get-all-child-list-from-firebase-android

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");    
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
   @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
       for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            String uid=data.child("uid").getValue().toString();
            if(uid.equals((mCurrentUser.getUid()){
            String keyid=data.getKey();
            ref.child(keyid).child("title").setValue(newtitle);
            ref.child(keyid).child("image").setValue(newurl);
            ref.child(keyid).child("desc").setValue(newdesc);
           }
     }
   }
```

Have the location of the listener at `child("Blog")` and then iterate inside of it and get the key which is `keyid`. Then to update the values simple point it to the right location and update each one.

Comment: hey Peter i used email auth for posting data by auth users so i think this line is required  mDatabaseUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(mCurrentUser.getUid());

Comment: not accepting directly keyid in this code mDatabaseUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog").child(key_id_here);

Comment: ya i know i used id here instead of key_id_here as mentioned but not solving the issue

Comment: hey it effect all the post in the blog structure . All changes by updating one post i think due to mAuth may be

Comment: but all post are from different users so there be not change all the post can tell how to fix this

Comment: Sorry Peter i will not do this again id is mentioned above      String id = data.getKey();  I swear follow your rules but it is changing all the data in a structure

Comment: Sorry Peter i am irritating you but I am new on Firebase  I meant to say that if you make a update on particular post (image,title,desc) and rest other post by users seems to be same not that particular selected post only this issue happening

Comment: yep Peter Sir Current user and that single one post by the user i.e. why i told maybe mAuth will work here but don't know how

Answer (score 0):

You're using getKey() on your base blog DB reference (/Blog). You need to create a new node within that reference with push(), and then getKey() on your newly created child.

`final String id = mDatabase.push().getKey();`