# Android Kotlin How to Get Records from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am a beginner in android programming with Kotlin.  I'm close on this, but missing something.  Google is not showing me just what I need.  Hoping someone here can.

I'm using `android studio 4.1.1`, `kotlin` and `Firebase`

I have several records in my test Firebase database.

[image: screenshot of Firebase db]

each of these records has data, but when I use `println` in my code one part is showing null and it is not hitting another `println` at all.

my code - in part

```
WeightExercise.kt:

...
// i write records to the db like this:

val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("weights")
        val recordID = ref.push().key
        val userId = Global.userID

       if (recordID != null){
            ref.child(userId).child(recordID).setValue(weight).addOnCompleteListener{
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Weight Record rated successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
...
```

```
DisplayWeightsActivity.kt:

val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("weights")
val uidRef = ref.child("weights").child(uid)
val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
       println("$$$$$$ dataSnapshot: ${dataSnapshot.toString()}")
       for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {
           println("#$#$#$#$#$  in override dataSnapshot.children")
           val muscle = ds.child("muscleGroup").getValue(String::class.java)
           val exercise = ds.child("exerciseText").getValue(String::class.java)
           val date = ds.child("date").getValue(String::class.java)
           Log.d("TAG", date + " " + muscle + " " + exercise)
       }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
       Log.d("DB ERROR", databaseError.message) //Don't ignore errors!
    }
    uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
}
```

In my Logcat window I see this:

```
$$$$$$ dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot { key = oB3pzvhAr6foyhGZUuvFl4CECOw2, value = null }
```

But the `println("#$#$#$#$#$  in override dataSnapshot.children")` does not print.

The key above `oB3pzv...` matches my userid, so it sees that. I'm not sure what `value = null` means.  Is it not seeing the children records?   How do I get the children records under weights >> userId ?

Comment: Your code is reading from `/weights/weights` (double), which doesn't exist in your JSON. My guess is that one of these lines is not supposed to have the `weights` node in there: `val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("weights")` or `val uidRef = ref.child("weights").child(uid)`.

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen  That was it.  so blind am i. I changed the second one to: <code>val uidRef = ref.child(uid)</code>

Comment: Good to hear that John  I voted to close your question as a typo, as I doubt anyone caught in the same situation will bump into it in the future.

Comment: Thanks, @FrankvanPuffelen  I have a follow up question.  Should I create a new thread?

Comment: A new thread for what?

Comment: I have all my data in the dataSnapshot.Each record looks like:  DataSnapshot { key = oB3pzvhAr6foyhGZUuvFl4CECOw2, value = {-MQEY5E7228LT34LNpZ-={....    I pass it to my recyclerviewadapter as a dataSnapshot.  In:  fun onBindViewHolder(holder: WeightViewHolder, position: Int) {  I do not know how to apply 'position' to get each record.  Is this possible?  I'm looking at converting the dataSnapshot to an ArrayList, but I've not done that before.  so much to learn

Comment: Ah, I see. So you have another problem after fixing the one I commented about. In that case please open a new question with its own updated [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It might be very similar to this one, but at the very least the double `weights/weight` should be fixed in there.

Comment: This may help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886546/how-to-get-all-child-list-from-firebase-android