# Firebase retrieving the child value from realtime database of Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Firebase and Android. I have stored user authentication details (name, profile image other than email ID) in my Firebase account. I want to retrieve those data (such as names etc.,) to the other part of my app. How can I retrieve my realtime database child values?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27848313/firebase-retrieve-child-android?rq=1

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("userID").child("displayName");

// Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String displayName = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
        System.out.println(displayName );
    }
```

For more:

[Read and Write Data on Android - Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Comment: dataSnapshot.getValue().toString(); goes to an error.called=method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the names of all the users, then you can do it like this

```
DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        mRef.child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Log.v("user_name", snapshot.getValue(String.class));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```